# Emacs fontifying doc comments

Tags: regex, emacs

In emacs when you do doc comments it correctly highlights docs that start with `/**`. Example:

```
/**
 * @brief: Test
 */
```

would be correctly fontified with font-lock-string-face and font-lock-doc-face.

Some people do doc comments with `///` instead and Emacs does not fontify this using font-lock-doc-face and font-lock-string-face. Is there a way to get emacs to fontify those types of doc comments as well? I am trying to accomplish this for C/C++ but a flexible solution would be nice.

EDIT:
After looking through the emacs source code a bit I see that this is handled in cc-fonts.el in the lisp/progmodes folder. It looks like `c-font-lock-doc-comments` can be called with different prefix arguments and modifying this might fix it. When I get more time I will try and see what needs to be changed.

Comment: Not a C++ user, but when switching to c++-mode, both `/*` and `///` get the indentation?

Comment: @Dualinity I'm not talking about indentation I'm talking about fontifying.

Comment: It also gets the red (in my case) font.

Comment: @Dualinity What version of Emacs? I'm 24.3.5.

Comment: I now see that it does not fontify lines after the initial line with `///` (is there a closing `comment-end` character for those as well?)

Comment: @Dualinity I don't think so. For some reason my C++ mode doesn't highlight any docs only c-mode works for me. So c++-mode doesn't highlight any and c-mode only highlights the /** ones.

Comment: the bzr repo on savannah.org. I'm using fedora 16 which didn't have ver 24 in the repo so I just pulled the source. Same happens on other versions though.

Comment: Just to get things straight: Isn't `///` only meant to be for single line comments? Not to enclose a region of text?

Comment: The natural way to get Emacs to do something new is to file a feature request at the Emacs bug tracker. Especially if you're already building from trunk.

Comment: @Dmitry I know it's just that I wanted to see if there was something that could easily be changed to achieve this.

Comment: @Dualinity Yeah that's true although people just do /// on multiple lines to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @wvxvw Going to check that out now

Comment: @Dualinity Check out my answer for a way to get this working in all modes with the /// comments (or any type of comment you would like).

Comment: Check this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35015/2418 - it shows how to setup your own doxygen highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(defconst custom-font-lock-keywords
  `((,(lambda (limit)
        (c-font-lock-doc-comments "///"
                                  limit gtkdoc-font-lock-doc-comments)))))
(setq-default c-doc-comment-style (quote (gtkdoc javadoc autodoc custom)))
```

Not too bad just drop in a .emacs file. You can customize the keywords but I just use the default gtkdoc keywords since that works for me.

Thanks to wvxvw for the pointer to `c-doc-comment-style`.

After testing for a bit this does not work for multi line `///` comments (each starting with `///` on separate lines). Will edit if fixed.